# Is there a similar command to multisearch in Splunk for non-streaming searches?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-sdk

I understand in Splunk that **multisearch** allows multiple searches to run in parallel. However, it's only for streaming searches. Is there a similar command or way to run non-streaming searches in parallel?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

Non-streaming commands, [by definition](https://docs.splunk.com/Splexicon:Non-streamingcommand), run on the Search Head that initiated the search - and nowhere else.

They're *typically* expected to run *after* all the streaming searches have happened, for any finalization/manipulation of the returned data from all Search Peers running the search

If you run non-streaming commands earlier than necessary in your SPL, you will slow the search down (potentially very dramatically)

Using the Splexicon example cited above, if you run a [`sort`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/sort) "early" (eg before [`stats`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/stats)), you force the initiating Search Head to do *all* of the data processing, instead of merely collating what every eligible Search Peer has preprocessed into a final resultset